# cbind() is changing date formatting

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to create a subset of a data frame and when I do so, R switches the formatting of the date column.  Any idea why or how to fix this?

```
> head(spyPr2)
        Date   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume Adj.Close
1 12/30/2011 126.02 126.33 125.50 125.50  95599000    125.50
2 12/29/2011 125.24 126.25 124.86 126.12 123507200    126.12
3 12/28/2011 126.51 126.53 124.73 124.83 119107100    124.83
4 12/27/2011 126.17 126.82 126.06 126.49  86075700    126.49
5 12/23/2011 125.67 126.43 125.41 126.39  92187200    126.39
6 12/22/2011 124.63 125.40 124.23 125.27 119465400    125.27
> spyPr2$Date <- as.Date(spyPr2$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
> head(spyPr2)
        Date   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume Adj.Close
1 2011-12-30 126.02 126.33 125.50 125.50  95599000    125.50
2 2011-12-29 125.24 126.25 124.86 126.12 123507200    126.12
3 2011-12-28 126.51 126.53 124.73 124.83 119107100    124.83
4 2011-12-27 126.17 126.82 126.06 126.49  86075700    126.49
5 2011-12-23 125.67 126.43 125.41 126.39  92187200    126.39
6 2011-12-22 124.63 125.40 124.23 125.27 119465400    125.27
> spyPr2 <- data.frame(cbind(spyPr2$Date, spyPr2$Close, spyPr2$Adj.Close))
> str(spyPr2)
'data.frame':   1638 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X1: num  15338 15337 15336 15335 15331 ...
 $ X2: num  126 126 125 126 126 ...
 $ X3: num  126 126 125 126 126 ...
> head(spyPr2)
     X1     X2     X3
1 15338 125.50 125.50
2 15337 126.12 126.12
3 15336 124.83 124.83
4 15335 126.49 126.49
5 15331 126.39 126.39
6 15330 125.27 125.27
```

UPDATE:

```
> spyPr2 <- data.frame(cbind(spyPr2["Date"], spyPr2$Close, spyPr2$Adj.Close))
Error in `[.data.frame`(spyPr2, "Date") : undefined columns selected
> spyPr2 <- data.frame(cbind(spyPr2[,"Date"], spyPr2$Close, spyPr2$Adj.Close))
Error in `[.data.frame`(spyPr2, , "Date") : undefined columns selected
```

UPDATE 2:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(15338, 15337, 15336, 15335, 
15331, 15330), class = "Date"), Open = c(126.02, 125.24, 126.51, 
126.17, 125.67, 124.63), High = c(126.33, 126.25, 126.53, 126.82, 
126.43, 125.4), Low = c(125.5, 124.86, 124.73, 126.06, 125.41, 
124.23), Close = c(125.5, 126.12, 124.83, 126.49, 126.39, 125.27
), Volume = c(95599000L, 123507200L, 119107100L, 86075700L, 92187200L, 
119465400L), Adj.Close = c(125.5, 126.12, 124.83, 126.49, 126.39, 
125.27)), .Names = c("Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", 
"Volume", "Adj.Close"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Have you tried using `[` selection instead of `$`? eg `spyPr2["Date"]`

Comment: Show us the results of `dput(head(spyPr2))` so we don't have to go to trouble of creating our own data to see what is happening. I suspect the default `cbind()` method is the problem here but would like to run code on my own machine to check.

Comment: No, sorry, I meant the output from `dput()` *before* you process it. I.e. Give is your input data (but we only need the 6 lines you show.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Obvious answer is **don't do subsetting like that**! Use the appropriate tools. What is wrong with

```
spyPr2.new <- spyPr2[, c("Date", "Close", "Adj.Close")]
```

?

To explain the behaviour you are seeing, you need to understand what `$` returns and how `cbind()` works. `cbind()` is one of those oddities in R wherein method dispatch is not done via the usual method but is instead handled via special code buried in the internals of R. This is all the R code behind `cbind()`:

```
> cbind
function (..., deparse.level = 1) 
.Internal(cbind(deparse.level, ...))
<bytecode: 0x24fa0c0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Not much help, eh? There are methods for data frames and `"ts"` objects however:

```
> methods(cbind)
[1] cbind.data.frame cbind.ts*       

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

Before I do the reveal, also note what `$` returns (`dat2` is your 6 lines of data after converting `Date` to a `"Date"` object):

```
> str(dat2$Date)
 Date[1:6], format: "2011-12-30" "2011-12-29" "2011-12-28" "2011-12-27" ...
```

This is a `"Date"` object, which is a special vector really.

```
> class(dat2$Date)
[1] "Date"
```

The key thing is that it is **not** a data frame. So when you use `cbind()`, the internal code is seeing three vectors and the internal code creates a matrix.

```
> (c1 <- cbind(dat2$Date, dat2$Close, dat2$Adj.Close))
      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
[1,] 15338 125.50 125.50
[2,] 15337 126.12 126.12
[3,] 15336 124.83 124.83
[4,] 15335 126.49 126.49
[5,] 15331 126.39 126.39
[6,] 15330 125.27 125.27
> class(c1)
[1] "matrix"
```

There can only be numeric or character matrices in R so the `Date` object is converted to a numeric vector:

```
> as.numeric(dat2$Date)
[1] 15338 15337 15336 15335 15331 15330
```

to allow `cbind()` to produce a numeric matrix.

You can force the use of the data frame method by calling it explicitly and it does know how to handle `"Date"` objects and so doesn't do any conversion:

```
> cbind.data.frame(dat2$Date, dat2$Close, dat2$Adj.Close)
   dat2$Date dat2$Close dat2$Adj.Close
1 2011-12-30     125.50         125.50
2 2011-12-29     126.12         126.12
3 2011-12-28     124.83         124.83
4 2011-12-27     126.49         126.49
5 2011-12-23     126.39         126.39
6 2011-12-22     125.27         125.27
```

However, all the explanation aside, you are trying to do the subsetting in a very complex manner. `[` as a subset function works just fine:

```
> dat2[, c("Date", "Close", "Adj.Close")]
        Date  Close Adj.Close
1 2011-12-30 125.50    125.50
2 2011-12-29 126.12    126.12
3 2011-12-28 124.83    124.83
4 2011-12-27 126.49    126.49
5 2011-12-23 126.39    126.39
6 2011-12-22 125.27    125.27
```

`subset()` is also an option but not needed here:

```
> subset(dat2, select = c("Date", "Close", "Adj.Close"))
        Date  Close Adj.Close
1 2011-12-30 125.50    125.50
2 2011-12-29 126.12    126.12
3 2011-12-28 124.83    124.83
4 2011-12-27 126.49    126.49
5 2011-12-23 126.39    126.39
6 2011-12-22 125.27    125.27
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks very much.  Didn't even think of doing it that way.

Comment: cbind.data.frame is helpful for merging date columns in other contexts as well.

Comment: Awesome ! And thank you for providing the `cbind.data.frame` method. I had to do a cbind on columns from different tables hence, could not use the subsetting method.

Answer (score 5):

I think I might call this a hidden instance of the `drop = FALSE` gotcha with data frames.

When you use `cbind`, it only uses the data frame method if at least one of the components are also data frames. Otherwise, everything is converted to a single type in order to construct a matrix.

Thus, calling `cbind` on elements like `spyPr2$Date` or `spyPr2[,'Date']` will result in a matrix (losing the date structure), which will not be magically restored by wrapping it all in `data.frame`.

You can do this if you use `[` to select each column, but only by using `drop = FALSE` which prevents R from converting the result to a vector (which lands you right back where you started with R coercing the result to a matrix):

```
cbind(spyPr2[,'Date',drop = FALSE],spyPr2[,'Close'])
```

is sufficient, since you only need one of the components to be a data frame.

But Gavin is right in general, you shouldn't be subsetting your data frame this way.